# Aggregating table in MySQL excluding character string

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

So I have a table as follows:

```
Metric  Date         Site
GroupA  02/03/2015   Hector.com
GroupA  02/03/2015   Google.com
GroupB  02/03/2015   Hector.com
GroupB  02/03/2015   Booerns.org
GroupC  02/03/2015   abc.com
GroupA  02/04/2015   Jericho.org
```

And I need to get it into the following format. I exclude in my count any instance of `abc.com` in the Site column.

```
Metric  Date        Count
GroupA  02/03/2015      2
GroupB  02/03/2015      1
GroupA  02/04/2015      1
```

so essentially I would like to group all common Metrics together and count them for each day. The number of times a date appears should be equal to the distinct number of different metrics which appeared on that day. Additionally, if abc.com appears in the Site column, anywhere in the string (it can be like abc.com/bornhfuuen=email) it must not be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the *rows* using `where`:

```
select metric, date, count(*)
from t
where site <> 'abc.com'
group by metric, date;
```

If you want to remove any *groups* that would have `'abc.com'`, you can use `having`:

```
select metric, date, count(*)
from t
group by metric, date
having sum(site = 'abc.com') = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly,

Please try the below query.

```
select metric, date , count(distinct site) as cnt
from table
where coalesce(Site,'x') not like '%abc.com%'
group by metric, date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to exclude certain rows, you can do that with a WHERE clause before you GROUP the results:

```
SELECT Metric, Date, COUNT(1)
FROM myTable
WHERE Site NOT LIKE '%abc.com%'
GROUP BY Metric, Date
```

*(Admittedly, this is SQL Server compliant syntax)*

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Metric, Date, Count(1)
FROM
  (SELECT Metric, Date
   FROM table1
   WHERE site not like '%abc.com%') T
GROUP BY Metric, Date
```